# Heroku - No web processes running

Tags: heroku

When I was trying to open my app in Heroku, I receive this message:

Application error

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
`heroku logs --tail`

```py
heroku logs --tail

at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=weatherpredictor01.herokuapp.com request_id=7c54935e-7f52-406b-ac78-e0d736db1b0b fwd="42.107.76.34" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-02-19T04:28:53.698738+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=weatherpredictor01.herokuapp.com request_id=8630c90b-b008-415a-abc0-5fa145f59f45 fwd="42.107.76.34" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

```py
# Procfile

web: gunicorn app:app
```

Comment: Where is the location of `Procfile` in the project?

Comment: @GitauHarrison, this isn't an issue of the web process not being _defined_. There just aren't any dynos running it.

Comment: You can force Heroku to spin up a web dyno using `heroku ps:scale web=1`, thereby executing your `gunicorn` command.